# Ruby XMLParsing Exception

Tags: ruby

I get a ParseException every time I try to parse a http get_response data in Ruby. The Exception is because of the presence of '&' in the data. How do I solve this?

Illegal character '&' in raw string (REXML::ParseException)

Answer (score 0):

Is the data you're passing to the parser XML? Do other parsers complain about it?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the data that you're trying to parse is well-formed XML. If you are trying to pass it HTML or RSS from the web, then it almost certainly isn't well-formed XML (HTML is not XML, though XHTML might be, and while RSS is supposed to be XML, there are lots of bad RSS generators out there that general RSS that is not well formed or invalid).

If you need to parse HTML, try [Hpricot](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot). If you need to parse RSS, use the built-in RSS parser; there are some examples [here](http://www.rubyrss.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to parse HTML consider using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/).

```
Nokogiri::HTML("<html>...</html>")
```

You can also try `Nokogiri::XML` but I believe that requires valid markup.